# How to build and structure in Java

Tags: java, oop

I want to define a String object that have my table names, and in every table I can access my column row name.

Let me explain that with an example:

I have two tables; "tasks" and "parts".

In `tasks` I have 2 columns; "id" and "taskName".

In `parts` table I have 2 columns as well; "id" and "name".

Now I would like to know how I have to define an object, so that I can access the name of any column in this way:

```
TABLE.tasks.parts
```

I want something like this (but this one is wrong!)

```
public final class TABLES {

    public final static String TASKS    = "tasks";
    public final static String CHUNKS   = "chunks";

    public final static class TASKS{

        public final String COLUMN_ID        = "id";
        public final String COLUMN_NAME      = "taskName";
    };

    public final static class CHUNKS{

        public static final String COLUMN_ID        = "id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME      = "name";
    };

}
```

Comment: I think you just need to get the final static down for the classes.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, but did you consider using `enum`?

Comment: You seem to be trying to create a Java object that reflects some relational schema, is that right? If so, I suggest that you either have a look at JPA or something totally different like jOOQ. If not, or if you just want some lightweight picture of your schema, then go with enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA, the Java Persistency API, can do that and more. I was impressed from the support of eclipseLink (the reference JPA implementation) in the NetBeans IDE.

It may translate (part of) a database into database model classes just like mentioned. And concrete data access object classes. Furthermore there is a criteria API to build entire SQL SELECTs this way.

Be aware, that generating the model classes goes a bit further that the basic JPA. You have to do a bit of internet search, or try out NetBeans / New / Persistence / Entity classes from database.

- Netbeans support ([video](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/jpa-eclipselink-screencast.html)).
- A pure JPA [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html) - largely without the generated model classes you desire, but to get the grasp of basic JPA.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right way to go about it.
If you want a database, use a database like SQLite.
If you want objects, you could do it like this:

```
public class Tables{

public final static Task task;
public final static Chunk chunk;

// or ArrayList<Tasks> tasks if there is more than one task/chunk

}
```

and then another file Tasks.java

```
public class Task{

    public final String id;
    public final String name;

}
```

and Chunk.java:

```
public class  Chunk{

    public final String id;
    public final String name;

}
```

Comment: i always did this way that you said. bout now i want to have some place to put all table column name in it and have easy access to them

Comment: Yeah so use the ArrayList in my comment above and then you can access them with `Tables.task.get(i).id`

Answer (score 0):

You should user interface. Whenever you want to use those contestants in your application, just implement interface which have only constants in it..cheer..

```
public final class TABLES implements TASKS, CHUNKS{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TASKS.COLUMN_ID);    
        System.out.println(CHUNKS.COLUMN_ID);   
    }
}

interface TASKS{
    public final String COLUMN_ID        = "id";
    public final String COLUMN_NAME      = "taskName";
}

interface CHUNKS{
    public static String COLUMN_ID        = "id";
    public static String COLUMN_NAME      = "name";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
public class TripleField {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(TABLE.tasks.id);
    System.out.println(TABLE.tasks.taskName);
}
}

final class TABLE {
final static TASKS tasks = new TASKS();
}

class TASKS {
final String id = "myID";
final String taskName ="myTaskName";
}
```